# Java Error unexpected type required: variable; found: value in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to allocate a random ArrayList array with size elements, fill with
random values between 0 and 100

This is the block that I keep getting the error in

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> generateArrayList(int size)
{
    // Array to fill up with random integers
    ArrayList<Integer> rval = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);

    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i=0; i<rval.size(); i++)
    {
        rval.get(i) = rand.nextInt(100);
    }

    return rval;
}
```

I've tried the .set and .get methods but neither of them seem to work

I keep getting the error unexpected type required: variable; found: value

It is throwing the error at .get(i)

Comment: On the right side of an `=` sign you need a value.  On the left side you need a variable.  A variable is (usually) a value, but not vice-versa.

Comment: See manouti's answer, but where you're going wrong in your thinking is in assuming that `new ArrayList<Integer>(size)` will create an `ArrayList` with `size` elements in it. It doesn't: it creates an *empty* list with *capacity* for `size` elements. (And in any case the capacity will grow as needed, so you don't usually have to worry about it.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
rval.get(i) = rand.nextInt(100);
```

with

```
rval.add(rand.nextInt(100));
```

Also the `for` loop will iterate zero times when `rval.size()` is used because the list is initially empty. It should use the parameter `size` instead. When you initialize the list using `new ArrayList<Integer>(size)`, you are only setting its *initial capacity*. The list is still empty at that moment.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```